# Conditional expectation in terms of CDFs

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

I have a variable $\omega$ that is lognormal, that is, when we take the log of $\omega$ the distribution is normal. I saw in a paper the following result:

$$ E\left[\omega | \omega\geq \bar{\omega} \right] = \dfrac{1-\Phi(z-\sigma)}{1-\Phi(z)}$$

where $z = \dfrac{log(\bar{\omega}) + 0.5\sigma^2}{\sigma}$ and where $\Phi(z)$ denotes the CDF of the standard normal variable $z$. Also, $\log(\bar{\omega}) \sim N(-\dfrac{1}{2}\sigma^2, \sigma^2)$

How can you reach to the conditional expectation shown above? I am more familiar with this:

$$E\left[\omega | \omega\geq \bar{\omega} \right] = \int_{\bar{\omega}}^{\infty}\dfrac{\omega f(\omega) d\omega}{1-F(\omega)}$$

How can this be re-expressed in terms of CDFs as above?

The result shown above is [here](http://www.econ.nyu.edu/user/gertlerm/BGGHandbook.pdf) in page 1385

Comment: I suggest biting the bullet and compute the last integral.

Comment: I am stuck with this a bit, could you suggest something? I might be doing it wrong because I still dont see the link with the first expectation in terms of standard normal distributions. I particularly dont know how one can get $\Phi(z-\sigma)$.

Comment: $P(\omega\ge\bar\omega)=P(\log\omega\ge\log\bar\omega)=P(N\ge z)$ - this gives you the denominator in the formula. You are left to show that $E(e^{-\frac 1 2\sigma^2+\sigma N};N\ge z)=P(N\ge z-\sigma)$. It holds true for $z=\infty$ and derivatives of both sides with respect to $z$ are equal, so it holds for all $z$.